# Compute the Cardinality of a quotient set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $R$ be a an Equivalence relation on $\Bbb{R}$ defined by: $$aRb \Leftrightarrow (a-b)\in \Bbb{Z}$$
What is the cardinality of $|\Bbb{R}/R|$?   where $\Bbb{R}/R$ is the quotient set of $\Bbb{R}$ under $R$.

Comment: Try searching the site before posting.

Comment: You can do tricks with digits. If $x$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$, first find $a=2x-1$ between $-1$ and $1$. Then write $|a|$ in decimal form as $|a|=0.a_1a_2a_3a_4...$. Now you can construct the number $...a_4a_2.a_1a_3...$ (decimal point between $a_2$ and $a_1$) Give this number the same sign as $a$ and you have a surjection from $(0,1)$ onto $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It surprises me that the same question was posted just 12 hours ago. Is it a homework problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that the map $g:\Bbb R\to[0,1)$, $g(x)= x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ is surjective and it satisfies $g(x)=g(y)\Leftrightarrow xRy$. Therefore it induces a bijection $\widetilde g:\Bbb R/R\to [0,1)$ such that $\widetilde g([x]_R)=g(x)$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.